# BackboneJS collection iterated via each returns default model instead of exact defined model

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller, typescript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I need some help here. I have defined model and collection in BackboneJS

```
export class MyModel extends Backbone.Model {
    constructor(options?) {
        this.urlRoot = 'apiURL/getmymodel';
        this.idAttribute = 'ID';
        super(options);
    }

    myMethod(): any {
        ...
    }
}

export class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
    model = MyModel;
    url = 'apiURL/getmycollection';
}
```

In UnderscoreJS template I want to call MyModel method myMethod() like this

```
myCollection.each(function(myModel) {
    myModel.myMethod();
}
```

But I get exception while calling myMethod()

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Am I doing sth. wrong or the each is not possible to cast the model in collection to defined type? If not, why is the type of collection item even defined?

Comment: Right now the workaround can be done via cast to model like this
`myModel = new MyModel(myCollection.models[i].attributes)`.
But thats not the way I want to do it for every each.

Comment: You have all you need in the question. I call all the stuff correctly, but there is a problem, that even when I call `myCollection.get('modelCID')` I get instance of class Backbone.Model instead of instance of class MyModel.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the Typescript compiler thinks that the type of `myModel` is `Backbone.Model`, like if your code was:

```
myCollection.each(function(myModel: Backbone.Model) {  // Error!
    myModel.myMethod();
});
```

Which fails as `myMethod()` does not exist on `Backbone.Model`. Backbone type definitions are defined in your `Backbone.d.ts` file.

To fix your issue, you need to help Typescript with type inference by specifying your model type:

```
myCollection.each(function(myModel: MyModel) {  // Works as you expect
    myModel.myMethod();
});
```

**Edit:** Ok, I did recreate it in a single typescript file, so it worked it in that context.

I think the best way to solve this issue is to define your `model` property directly on the `prototype`:

```
export class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection {
    url = 'apiURL/getmycollection';
}
MyCollection.prototype.model = MyModel;
```

Comment: Well, that is not the problem, because I execute the each over collection in the plain javascript in UnderscoreJS template, so Typescript doesn't interfear with this code. Even when I debug the code, I can see the collection typed as `MyCollection`, but the model I get is `Backbone.Model`